# Using state attributes to maintain old records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to keep old records that would be normally destroyed. For example, an user joins a project, and is kicked from it later on. I want to keep the user_project record with something that flags the record as inactive. For this I use a state attribute in each model to define the current state of each record.

Almost all my "queries" want just the "active" records, the records with state == 1, and I want to use the ActiveRecord helpers (find_by etc). I don't want to add to all the "find_by's" I use a "_and_state" to find only the records that are active.

This is what I have now:

```
u = UserProject.find_by_user_id_and_project_id id1, id2
```

This is what I will have for every query like this for all models:

```
u = UserProject.find_by_user_id_and_project_id_and_state id1, id2, 1
```

What is the most cleaner way to implement this (the state maintenance and the cleaner query code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a scope in your model `UserProject`:

```
class UserProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, where(:state => 1)
end
```

and "filter" your queries:

```
u = UserProject.active.find_by_user_id_and_project_id id1, id2
```

if you "almost allways" query the active `UserProject`s only, you can define this scope as `default_scope` and use `unscoped` if you want to query all records:

```
class UserProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:state => 1)
end

u = UserProject.find_by_user_id_and_project_id id1, id2  # only active UserProjects
u = UserProject.unscoped.find_by_user_id_and_project_id id1, id2 # all states
```

Comment: and if I create the scope in the ActiveRecord class, is It applicable to all models?

Comment: in the rare case that **ALL** your models have the column `state` with the same meaning, yes. But it's better to declare your own sub class and derive your models with state from this class.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to just add this to Martin's answer, but my edit has to be reviewed, so even though Martin's answer was great, we can improve on it a little with the idea of default scopes.  A default scope is always applied to finders on the model you add them to unless you specifically turn off the default scope:

```
class UserProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:state => 1)
end
```

The example Martin gave then becomes:

```
u = UserProject.find_by_user_id_and_project_id id1, id2
```

In this case, even without specifying that you want state == 1, you will only get active records.  If this is almost always what you want, using a default scope will ensure you don't accidentally leave off the '.active' somewhere in your code, potentially creating a hard-to-find bug.

If you specify your default scope like this:

```
default_scope :conditions => {:state => 1}
```

then newly created UserProjects will already have state set to 1 without you having to explicitly set it.

Here's more information on default scopes:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

Here's how to turn them off temporarily when you need to find all records:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/unscoped

Answer (score 1):

Here's a range of [soft deletion gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Soft_Delete) you may want to choose from, which offer a nice abstraction that's already been thought through and debugged:

- [rails3_acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/goncalossilva/rails3_acts_as_paranoid)
- [acts_as_archive](https://github.com/winton/acts_as_archive)
- [paranoia](https://github.com/radar/paranoia)

Although if this happens to be your first Rails app, I second Martin's advice of rolling your own implementation.